Javascript TinyMCE Post-Initialization Indentation Change
I am wokring with tinymce - great editor and very intuitive.
I want the ability to change the standard indentation px after initialisation. I am initialising like:
tinymce.init({
...,
indentation: "25px",
})
This works perfectly and when the user indents - it indents with 25px. I want to be able to change this after initialisation.
I have looked through the tinymce.activeEditor attributes and have not found this setting.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Solutions would be even better.
Many thanks
